# Crystal reports, how to set specific rows in a given report format

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I need to have a report as follows. 
[image]

My issue is how to set the specific rows as the given format. I need to show the "All Contributions", "Participnt Contribution" and "Comparison" rows then a gray line and the other parameter rows.

I tried with grouping, but unable to have the gray line before the parameter rows.

All the data rows are coming from one data source. a C# data set.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So individual parameters is a record that is not in datasource but you need to add in report? if yes then is the data in description column is coming from single column of datasource?

Comment: No Individual parameters is also a record coming from data source with the rest of the records. The issue is how to get a report with the given format. Like with the gray color line and display the rest of the records.